# Push change of active cell to share users in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I use Google Sheets as a live technical running order in live and virtual events.  I direct the show and technicians follow my running order live.  When I make updates, obviously their sheets change too.  I highlight the row that reflects where we are in the show, so that they can see that at a glance.
Now I would like to be able to push the technician's instance of the sheet to follow my active cell or a check box I tick on a particular row.  The aim is for their spreadsheet to automatically scroll to where I am in the show, without them having to manually scroll.
Could any kind soul suggest a means to do this, please?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sheet scripts and don't know if that could help, but you could add a tick box column on your main sheet, then as you progress down, you could tick the previous items off. On a speparate sheet you could use the `QUERY` function to display your main sheet, but hide the rows you've ticked. Then they wouldn't need to scroll, they'd just see your current position. If you can share a sample sheet (keeping your structure) I could help with the `QUERY`

Comment: Please share a sample spreadsheet to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment, if your tick box is say Column A on Sheet1, Sheet2 query could be like this in cell A1:

`query(Sheet1!A:Z,"select B,C,D,E,F,G where A =false",1)`

You'd obviously alter your range `Sheet1!A:Z`, and the columns you want to display (and their order) `select B,C,D,E,F,G`, and which column has the tick boxes `where A =false`